# NFC wand (or shield, or other) for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc

I am developing a system to register visitors. The visitors wear a wristband containing an NFC tag.

In order to read the tag, I am currently using a cheap Samsung Android phone, with built in NFC reader, which costs around GBP 60 / Eur 77 / USD 87.

I am considering replacing the phone with a Raspberry Pi and am thinking about an NFC reader.

I *could* use a shield, and am open to recommendations, but it always seems uncomfortable tapping a phone to someone's wrist and I doubt that tapping a Pi would feel any more comfortable (especially if the Pi is wired for mains power).

Is there a cheap wand, or other device, which can be connected to the Pi for a less awkward scan of the wristband?

Budget will play a role in this, but I am not yet sure how much of a role (sorry).

Comment: You might look for a USB-based NFC reader, even if it is in a dongle form factor you could assemble it with an extension cable and some sort of sleeve or perhaps a 3d printed overcase.  You could also consider putting the reader on a pedestal the visitors place their own wrist over.